# Angular print string array without quotes

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-templates

I have a simple string array coming from a server:

```
[{"things":["me", "my"]}]
```

In my page, to display the array I have:

```
{{things}}
```

And it prints:

```
["me", "my"]
```

How do I control the printing, for instance, if I want to eliminate the brackets and quotes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can implement a scope function to display arrays as comma separated strings like shown in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j4kwbhe/1/)**.

```
$scope.array = ["tes","1","2","bla"];

$scope.arrayToString = function(string){
    return string.join(", ");
};
```

Now you can call this function within the template:

```
{{arrayToString(array)}}
```

---

**Update**

You can also use the `join()` method of arrays directly within the template without using an extra function inbetween as displayed within the [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5j4kwbhe/3/).

```
{{array.join(", ")}}
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you'll want [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for something like:

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="thing in things">
  {{ thing }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also create custom [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) optionally with some advanced formatting:

```
module.filter('formatArray', ['OptionalInjection', function(OptionalInjection) {
  return function(value) {
    if (!angular.isArray(value)) return '';
    return value.map(OptionalInjection.formatter).join(', ');  // or just return value.join(', ');
  };
}])
```

Then in `html` just write `{{yourArrayValue | formatArray}}`.